# Add dynamic value (from Angular) in an svg icon

Tags: html, angular, web, svg

I have an svg icon into which I want to display the value of a typescript variable. That variable comes from an api. Is that possible??

svg: `<svg id="Component_102_1" data-name="Component 102 – 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="20" viewBox="0 0 32 20"> <rect id="Rectangle_1674" data-name="Rectangle 1674" width="32" height="20" rx="10" fill="#0e70c7"/> </svg>`

ts: `this.countLife = this.filterLifePolicies.length;`

html: `<img class="ppp" id="what" src="../../assets/images/Component102_1.svg">`

So, somehow I need to pass the content of countLife into that svg.

Comment: ... well, did you try string interpolation for the prop, `<svg id="Component_102_1" some-attr="{{countLife}}" ... > </svg>

Comment: Yes..it didn't work

Comment: ok, try to property bind: `<svg [attr.data-something]="countLife" .. > `

Comment: I did the following in the template: ```<img [innerHTML]="countlife" class="ppp" id="what" src="../../assets/images/Component102_1.svg">``` It didn't appear but when i inspect I see the value

Comment: It's possible to modify SVGs with Angular binginds. First, it's not possible to do it if SVGs are included via `img` HTML tag. Instead paste the SVG's XML into your template and then add property bindings.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.
Just paste your SVG's code into template, and then bind your component data to `SVG` element.

For example how you modify height of SVG (with shorthand setting pixels as unit):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" [attr.height.px]="heightInPixels"></svg>
```

Note that `heightInPixels` is a variable defined in your component class.

**edit:**

If you want to display certain variable value as a text, try adding a [`<text>` node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) into your SVG with Angular binginds.

```
<text x="20" y="35" class="small">{{ myVariable}}</text>
```

Note that `x`, `y` (or any other property) you can modify as same as shown earlier by `[attr.x]` and so on.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't understand what I have to bind in my  case.. so it will be ```[???] = "countLife"``` I only want to display countLife value into that svg

Comment: Sorry for late comment @AndreasV. I'm not an expert in modifying or creating SVGs but maybe [`<text>` node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) will help you achieve what you want?
Edited my answer